# I deeply belong to myself or i belong deeply to myself?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-request, difference, idioms

I saw that many famous people have tattooed “I deeply belong to myself” while others “I belong deeply to myself”.  So can both be said?

Comment: Yes, both can be said. Anything can be said. What the pair of them mean is another question altogether. If you want a meaningful tattoo, better say something else.

Comment: “finding yourself, loving yourself and finally experiencing a deep sense of belonging in your own body. You are all you have“ I found this that made me think a lot.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shipunmanned Can you provide a source for these statements?

Comment: Yes, of course. https://artgallery.co.uk/i-belong-deeply-to-myself#

Comment: even warsan shire (a British poetess) said this

Comment: there is no need for hashtags in your question. There are tags for useful categorization of posts, but those hashtags are just noise. please [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/321473/edit) your question to remove them.

Comment: A personal name should be capitalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one is possible. The second one is more euphonic.

Despite Ronald's comment, I find the only way to apply "deeply" is as the quality of the belonging, regardless of which order you choose. (Other adverbs may show more of a difference.)

Note that it's not at all clear what it means to "belong deeply". Your comment that a poet wrote this is very telling. It has the ring of poetry, not of prose. The impression it gives is that it's acceptable as English, but vague in meaning.

Personally, I would understand "deeply" either as a generic intensifier or else as "fundamentally", "integrally".